# How To Use Eclipse To Make Android Apps

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm really not sure where I should ask this, so please just tell me where to ask this sort of questions.

My problem is that I'm trying to use Eclipse to create Android Apps but it seems like Android SDK that I need to make this happen is not available anymore. The link of the SDK redirects me to Android Studio which I don't want to use because it's too laggy in my device.

Can I still use Eclipse to make Android apps in 2021?

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for several years now.

Comment: You have to install Android ADT Bundle from third party links. Please note that, ADT bundle is discontinued and Android studio is the recommended way of development. In case you have no internet connection or less powerful machine then you can try ADT.

Comment: why don't try Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

you can install android plugin in your eclipse ide https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  after installed this plugin download android sdk in your computer via this link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html  good luck

Comment: Am I just going to install both of them then everything will be fine or am I going to have to move them to appropriate directories?

Comment: The sdk leads me to android studio. Am I just going to download the sdk below? the commandlines something ones

Comment: I'm having problems with the sdk